# How do you hide floating action buttons from the keyboard?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button, android-keypad

I have FloatingActionButtons and FloatingActionMenus in CoordinatorLayouts, but I also have some EditTexts in there too, with the adjustPan window mode. But when I go to click the EditTexts, the floating buttons/menus come up along with the keyboard and somewhat block the visible area (such as the row containing the EditText). Can I somehow prevent the floating items from coming up with the keyboard?

Answer (score 3):

There is a library which can listen to keyboard visibility, if the keyboard is visbile make the FAB to GONE or INVISIBLE.

https://github.com/yshrsmz/KeyboardVisibilityEvent